# modifying a struct with multiple threads c programming

Tags: c, multithreading, struct

I have been all over the internet with no one directly answering this question. So I have a struct in my main process and I need multiple threads to modify it. I know that I am going to need mutexs to protect the data, but is there any way to share pointers with out passing it as an arg in pthread_create. I understand that threads share the same memory address and there for if I allocate in one the other should have access to it. But with out passing a pointer how do the threads know that a certain pointer already exists.

Comment: To share the struct without passing it, you would need to make it a global variable.

Comment: Please explain why you don't want to pass it as an arg in `pthread_create`.

Comment: A useful answer to this question would require a lot more information. It would be particularly helpful to describe the type of work you want to get done. Otherwise, you get a very generic answer.

Comment: okay so i am making a multi threaded bank server. clients can connect to the server and change account values. i have to use mutex to protect these transactions. I have the understanding that threads share address space and therefor the same heap. and in my travels on the internet is says that i can allocate a pointer p in one thread in free it in another. does this mean I can reference the pointer and modify the memory while at the same time using mutex

Comment: I'd suggest doing some research first on [multithreaded programming](http://randu.org/tutorials/threads/). You may want to look into [message queues](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6930/how-is-a-message-queue-implemented-in-the-linux-kernel).  I'd suggest avoiding globals as they are too convenient, and look into  atomic operations if you want it to go really fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical answer to your question is that rather than passing the pointer directly to the thread when you call `pthread_create`, you instead pass a pointer to some higher-level structure that serves as your communication with the thread.

For example, say you are writing a network server that receives requests from clients and then needs to process those requests. The threads that process requests from clients would typically be passed the address of some kind of waitable queue. When a thread receives a request from a client, it would put that request in the waitable queue. The threads that process client requests are already waiting for things to be put on that queue, and they get the information about the request they need to process from the queue.

Comment: So I making a simple multithreaded bank server. I am supposed to use mutex to manage the threads. I believe that the solution you provided is above what I am supposed to do. I just want to know if I malloc a pointer p can I reference it in another thread? and if so how do these threads share that information

Comment: @kevman The phrase "malloc a pointer" makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @kevman The two threads access a common collection (such as a waitable queue) that serves to permit them to communicate with each other. A pointer to that collection can be passed to the thread in the `pthread_create` function.

Comment: The OP may not be ready to implement something like a waitable queue, but might be ready to use one that's already written. Such a queue can have a two function interface, "put thing on queue", "get thing from queue, waiting if necessary".